# Setting number of items on node express header

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have the following route :

```
   connection.query(`SELECT * FROM documento WHERE (descricao_detalhada LIKE '%`+searchValue+`%'  OR 
    descricao_reduzida LIKE '%`+searchValue+`%' OR 
    num_doc ='%`+searchValue+`%'  ) and id_tipo_documento IN (`+q+')' ,(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err)console.log(q)
        res.header('total-count',rows.length)
        res.json(rows.slice(pageM,pageM+10))
    })
```

And this is how I fetch it on react . :

```
 await API.get(`${searchField}/${page}/`+getQueryParamsUrl())
       .then((response) => {
        setTempReturn(response.data);
        setTotalItems(response['total-count'])
       })
```

It's working. I just don't know how to setTotalItems, which means the total number of items returned from my mysql query statement. I need it for pagination. How do I properly set that information in the header and retriev it on react js?

Comment: where do you want to setTotalItems? while requesting back to the server?

Comment: in a react js application, inside a useEffect hook. I have a useState hook [totalItems,setTotalItems] = React.useState(0)